# how to save start and midpoints of google map in MySQL database through php android?

Tags: android, mysql

how to save start and midpoints of google map route in MySQL database php android ? suppose someone make multiple clicks to draw a route including start ,mid points and end points, how to save these points to MySQL database and then retrieve them to show on map ??

Comment: php android? is there a download?

Comment: not getting you brother !!!!!